# Can't connect Android Studio with Oracle Database 19c

Tags: java, database, android-studio, ojdbc, oracle19c

I've recently tried to connect Android Studio with an OracleDB through ojdbc driver without success.

I'm using ojdbc8.jar, Oracle Database 19c and jdk1.8.0_241 on Windows10.

**I tried to do the exact same thing with the same code and components in Intellij and everything went well.**

When I try to connect to the database I received the following error:
[see_error_print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlQs3.png) "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/sql/DriverAction;" in the line Class.forName.

I have installed Android 28 and my gradle version is 3.6.2.. I tried to clean project, and invalidate caches/restart, but nothing seems to work.

In fact, in Android28 (Sdk) at java.sql, indeed the missing file isn't there, but exists in jdk.

I appreciate any help I can get, thank you!
P.S.: english is not my mother language, sorry if there are any mistakes.

Here is the code I used:

```
package com.lamtias.isplit.ActivityLogin;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.lamtias.isplit.Logic.ISplit;
import com.lamtias.isplit.R;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ISplit iSplit;
    private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ISplitDB";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "c##marcia";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "marcia";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        JDBCexample(DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_USERNAME, DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
    }

    public static void JDBCexample(String dbid, String userid, String passwd)
    {
        try {

            Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ISplitDB", userid, passwd);
            if(conn!=null)
                System.out.println ("oiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
            else
                System.out.println ("oeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            //stmt.executeUpdate( "insert into users values ('1', 'Perryridge')");
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println("SQLException : " + sqle);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, I still don't get the problem.

Comment: btw, i had fixed the same problem using ojdbc8.jar from Oracle OJDBC from Oracle 18.3 https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-ucp-183-downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the same problem using ojdbc8.jar from Oracle OJDBC 18.3:
https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-ucp-183-downloads.html

Comment: But still using Oracle 19c?

Comment: Yes, it works fine with Oracle 19c: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xtsql.SimpleAndroidOracleClient

Comment: By using ojdbc8.jar from Oracle OJDBC 18.3 I got this error:  https://imgur.com/a/Cg27wL2 well at least the error is different